# Simple REST API calls using Spring?

Tags: java, rest, android, spring

Okay I'm having a simple REST API that is now running. I also got a mobile app (Android) that would be ready for some network communication. But here is the thing:

I now got a fancy API created with [Spring](https://spring.io/) that I can use with Http-Requests:

```
package com.helloworld

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

This is all fine but how would I use this API in my Android mobile App? What I mean is that I don't know how to make those calls more elegantly and simple! I don't want to write for every request on my API something like this:

```
class HelloWorldTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String url = "http://192.168.42.229:8080/HelloWorldExample/helloWorld/displayMessage/" + msg; 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {

        String msg = "";
        for(String m : uri) { msg += m; }    

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, "Android");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid this? To be honest I believed that I would be able to just import something like a `helloworld-api.jar` after building my REST API project and then do something like this:

```
import com.helloworld

public void getServerHello() {

    HelloWorldController api;

    HelloWorld helloWorld = api.getHelloWorldMapping();
    helloWorld.displayMessage("How are you?");
}
```

And that this will be it. So is there a way to do something like this when writing a Spring REST API or will I really have to use something like a URI-builder and create for all kind of requests an additional `class <whatever>Task extends AsyncTask<?, ?, ?>` by myself?

Since the API is clearly defined it should be possible to do something like this, but is it?

I hope my question is clear - please let me know if not.

Comment: Could you clarify your examples? getServerHello() doesn't map well to the controller. What should getHelloWorldMapping() and displayMessage() do? Also, do you realize that REST is resource-based API (i.e. not RPC). I get a feeling that SOAP might be better fit for your needs ...

Comment: @qbd Well this is supposed to be a simple *pseudo* code example but what `displayMessage()` is supposed to do is basically just to run something similar like `HelloWorldTask.execute()`. I don't want to write this by myself as I think there should be a way to generate a "*client-side-interface*"-library extracted from a well defined REST API or something like that for me to use easily. To my usecase: I need a server that handles mobile App clients as well as provide an API for a web interface. I don't know if REST is here really my best choice but is it the wrong one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current project we have similar setting with a Java client and a RESTful backend based on Springs REST API. We use `apache-cxf-rs-client-api` to call our REST services from the clients.

1. Create an Interface for your Methods in your `HelloWorldController`.
2. Add `apache-cxf-rs-client-api` to your project (take a look for [more information](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html)).
3. Now you can call the interface on the client and Apache CXF will do the rest for you.

Comment: Looks nice and useful. Gonna' take it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.itech.payroll.dto.ComypanyDTO;
import com.itech.payroll.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.itech.payroll.dto.User;
import com.itech.payroll.repo.PayrollRepo;
import com.itech.payroll.service.PayrollService;
import com.itech.payroll.service.UserService;
/**
 * REST API Implementation Using REST Controller
 * */
@RestController
public class RestReqCntrl {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;    

    @Autowired
    private PayrollService payrollService;  


    //-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> registerUser(@RequestBody User user,    UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getFirstName());

        boolean flag = userService.registerUser(user);

         if (flag)
         {
             user.setStatusCode(1);
             user.setStatusDesc("PASS");
         }else{
             user.setStatusCode(0);
             user.setStatusDesc("FAIL");

         }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/registerUser").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user,headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }   

    //-------------------Authenticating the User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<User> authuser(@RequestBody User user,UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getFirstName());

        boolean flag = userService.authUser(user);

         if (flag)
         {
             user.setStatusCode(1);
             user.setStatusDesc("PASS");
         }else{
             user.setStatusCode(0);
             user.setStatusDesc("FAIL");

         }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/authuser").buildAndExpand(user.getFirstName()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user,headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }   

    //-------------------Create a Company--------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerCompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerCompany(@RequestBody ComypanyDTO comypanyDTO, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating comypanyDTO " + comypanyDTO.getCmpName());
        String result ="";
        boolean flag = payrollService.registerCompany(comypanyDTO);

         if (flag)
         {
             result="Pass";
         }else{
             result="Fail";

         }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/registerCompany").buildAndExpand(result).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result,headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }   


    //-------------------Create a Employee--------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Creating registerCompany " + employeeDTO.getEmpCode());
        String result ="";
        boolean flag = payrollService.registerEmpbyComp(employeeDTO);

         if (flag)
         {
             result="Pass";
         }else{
             result="Fail";

         }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/registerCompany").buildAndExpand(result).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(result,headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }   

    //-------------------Get Company Deatils--------------------------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCompanies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ComypanyDTO> > getCompanies(UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("getCompanies getCompanies ");
        List<ComypanyDTO> comypanyDTOs =null;
        comypanyDTOs = payrollService.getCompanies();
        //Setting the Respective Employees
        for(ComypanyDTO dto :comypanyDTOs){

            dto.setEmployeeDTOs(payrollService.getEmployes(dto.getCompanyId()));
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/registerCompany").buildAndExpand("LISt").toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<ComypanyDTO>>(comypanyDTOs,headers, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }   

}
```

Comment: jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar, jackson-core-2.5.3.jar, jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar   these jars are need to be import

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. Could you explain your code a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your method with [@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World!");
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is written to the response HTTP body. The above example will result in the text helloWorld being written to the HTTP response stream.

Write a Http Android client which sends the Http Request to your Spring app, the response will be in JSON format. Parse the JSON via Jquery & display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Volley or Retrofit. The latter is especially useful for setting up client side API calls super fast.

When I do something like this I usually reuse the server model if available (when I do both the client and the server for example).

Otherwise you can just convert a json to a pojo class and use it with Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

To write a api you need to follow below pattern:

package com.helloworld

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloWorldController {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "helloWorld";
    }
}
```

For more detail step by step learning you can follow [link](http://techiejungles.blogspot.com/2018/01/1-my-first-rest-api-with-spring-boot.html).